# Fixing a div element to a position when the page is zoomed, not while scrolling

Tags: html, css

I hav a div element like this:

```
<div class="AvailabilityDiv" style="margin: -15px 0 0 51%;">
     Available 
     <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litAvailabilityHeaderTop"></asp:Literal>
</div>
```

This positions the div where I want it, however when the page is zoomed I want to keep it where I put it. At the moment the element moves to the left if the user zooms out.
I have tried position: fixed but that only holds it when it scrolls, not zooms. My question is how can I hold this where it is when the user zooms in or out???

Comment: Why do you need to care about the user zooming in and out? This question is very difficult to answer without seeing more of your markup. Could you please add a snippet to your question which replicates the problem you're having?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use percentage margin. `style="margin: -15px 0 0 51%;"`

It's hard to know the problem without the code.

You can see [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/ianwong/0u2vo1bs/)

The "box1" without percentage margin will not move to left.
The "box2" with percentage margin will move to left.

Comment: @Alan you can see on [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/ianwong/0u2vo1bs/), maybe you margin to a div which is percentage.

Comment: Even without the percentage it is moving.... It is a div that is wrapped in other divs, could that be anything to do with it??

Comment: @Alan I don't get what you want. Do you want the div stay where it is? or stay relate to browser windows? click [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) to see more about css position.